# Swift nil has a numeric value?

Tags: swift, option-type

This is valid code in Swift:

```
println(nil < 1)
```

And the output will be true, likewise

```
println(nil > 1)
```

will be false (the number 1 is arbitrary, you can do the same for -1 and probably something else). The reason I ask is because I saw some code that tried to compare `"some_string".toInt()` to a numeric value and it compiled, which seems wrong considering `toInt()` returns `Int?`.

**My question is, should this be valid syntax in Swift? If so, what is the numeric value of nil?**

---

**Swift 3.0 Update:**

Looks like Swift Evolution tackled this issue by [removing the optional comparison operators](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md). This is no longer an issue in Swift 3.0 as it doesn't compile.

Comment: this looks like a bug to me.

Comment: `Int.min as Int? > nil`
`$R14: Bool = true` maybe it is intended to allow you compare two `Int?` and `Int.min > nil` give compile error

Comment: @BryanChen It's certainly interesting. I would definitely say a bug in this context but I'd really like to know how it's arriving at this conclusion.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd have said that nil is deliberately designed to be less than any conceivable value, so that a list of `Int?` values can be sorted. But I can't prove it: I've looked through the Swift Programming Language PDF and can't find the behavior of "nil compared to other values" documented anywhere. Maybe it's there and I just haven't found it yet.

Comment: @rmunn I know you can compare optionals to nil, but as far as I know you can't compare normal types to nil.

Comment: @Lucas - So is that comparison operator "promoting" the value 1 to an optional? E.g., treating the not-explicitly-typed literal value as if it had an implicit typecast to `Int?`? I haven't ever coded in Swift yet so I can't easily check that, but that would be one theory to explain this.

Comment: @rmunn That is the most logical explanation, I guess the question is whether that is a desired behavior. I'd assume Apple didn't want something like this in their type safe language :)

Comment: Interestingly, this **doesn't** work: `let i = 1; println(nil < i)`, nor does `let i: Int = 1; println(nil < i)`.  I guess that makes sense if `1` in `println(nil < 1)` is being directly promoted to `Int?`, but it still seems odd...

Comment: I'm seeing more and more support for the theory that the literal `1` is a valid value of the `Int?` type, and so Swift is auto-typecasting it to a type that's valid to be used in that comparison operation. `Int` is not valid to compare against `nil`, but `Int?` is valid. I'll go ahead and make this an answer so people can confirm (by up- or down-voting the answer) whether this is really what's happening.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe what is happening is that the literal `1` is being implicitly typecast to the `Int?` type by the comparison to `nil`. For those who aren't used to Swift, I'll explain a little further. Swift has a concept called "optionals", which can either have a value or be `nil`. (For anyone familiar with Haskell, this is basically the `Maybe` monad.) It's illegal to assign `nil` to a variable that wasn't explicitly defined as optional, so `let i: Int = nil` will be rejected by the compiler. This allows for several benefits which are out of the scope of this answer, and it's a rather clever way to do it.

What's happening here, though, is that the literal `1` is a valid value of several types: `Int`, `Int32`, `Int64`, `UInt32`, `UInt64`, etc., etc., etc. And it's *also* a valid value of the optional versions of those types: `Int?`, `Int32?`, etc.

So when the Swift compiler sees a comparison between a literal value and `nil`, it tries to find a type that both these values would be valid for. `1` is a valid value of the `Int?` type, and `nil` is also a valid value of the `Int?` type, so it applies the comparison operator with the type signature `(Int?, Int?) -> Bool`. (That's the comparison operator that takes two `Int?` values and returns a `Bool`). That operator's rules say that `nil` values sort lower than anything else, even `Int.min`, and so you get the result seen in the OP's question.

Comment: Incidentally, this wouldn't be possible in Haskell (as I understand it), because the `Maybe` monad is defined as having two possible values: either `Nothing` or `Just x` (where `x` can be of any type). And since `x` can never be implicitly promoted to `Just x`, the Haskell compiler would, given a comparison operator that compares the types `Maybe Int` and `Maybe Int`, forbid any comparison between `1` and `Nothing`, because the former is of type `Int` and there's no operator to compare `Int` and `Maybe Int`. (But comparing `Just 1` and `Nothing` would be valid: both are of type `Maybe Int`).

Comment: Correction to the parenthetical in my previous comment: `Nothing` is of value `Maybe x`, where `x` can be any type. But that matches the type `Maybe Int`, so the comparison would be valid.

Comment: One of the signatures of the `<` operator is: `func <<T : _Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool`; I believe that's where this is coming from. Writing a quick test function: `func test<T: Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?)` and calling `test(nil, 1)` works. Calling `println(_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(rhs))` inside that function prints `Swift.Optional`; calling `println(_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(rhs!))` prints `Swift.Int`. So, `rhs`, which was passed as `1` in the call is an `Int?`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, given how the Swift compiler tries to infer types.

Comment: This "optional comparison operator" has been removed in Swift 3: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md, and `print(1 < nil)` does no longer compile.