# Comparing Int and nil in swift

Tags: swift, foundation

I have a function that returns an optional Int (`Int?`).

I store the value returned from this function and then compare it to check whether it is larger or smaller than 0, then perform certain operations.

I was surprised to see that the following code doesn't trigger at least a compiler warning.

```
func someMethod() -> Int? {
   return nil
}

fun doWork() {
    let value = self.someMethod()
    if value < 0 {
        print("nil value is evaluated as < 0")
    }
}
```

Could someone please explain why nil evaluates to <0 in the code below?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26172911/swift-nil-has-a-numeric-value

Comment: Thanks for the pointer David, that does indeed answer my question.